# SAS to Python: MLE with only one variable

Tags: python, sas

I'm currently trying to write SAS Codes in Python, but I got a problem.
Right now I'm trying to do a MLE, but SAS only uses one variable.

This is the following SAS Code:

```
SET krm.mortgage;
IF 700 < FICO_Orig_time < 750;
RUN;
ods graphics on;
PROC MEANS DATA = krm.mortgage_FICO750;
VAR default_time;
RUN;
PROC LOGISTIC DATA = krm.mortgage_FICO750 DESCENDING; 
MODEL default_time = / RSQUARE LINK = Probit;
RUN;
QUIT;
ods graphics off;
```

The thing that's bugging me is that if I want to get a MLE in Python, it requires two arguments

```
Probit(endog, exog).fit()
```

My dependent variable endog is of course "default_time", but what should be my exog, as the original code in SAS doesn't depend on anything else?

Comment: May you provide sample data in a [reproducible form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391)?

Comment: It's a way to get whatever the equivalent of an 'odds ratio' is in probit regression.